# Setting up CAS Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

How to I can setup a CAS server in windows 2008 Domain?

I was given
a project to enable wireless authentication "802.1x" using the
Windows NFS server. I've configure the Wireless controller and the NFS server,
but I can’t seem to get the endpoints “Windows7” client to connect. I've been
researching and it’s been mention that I need to configure it using a domain
PKI. Can some someone shed some lights on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a secure 802.1x wireless infrastructure using Microsoft Windows

http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2012/05/30/creating-a-secure-802-1x-wireless-infrastructure-using-microsoft-windows.aspx

Understanding 802.1X authentication for wireless networks

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759077(v=WS.10).aspx

Guidance of CA installation:

Active Directory Certificate Services Step-by-Step Guide

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772393(v=WS.10).aspx

In addition, try the Test Lab guides.

Test Lab Guide: Deploying an AD CS Two-Tier PKI Hierarchy
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831348.aspx

AD CS and PKI Step-by-Steps, Labs, Walkthroughs, HowTo, and Examples
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4797.ad-cs-and-pki-step-by-steps-labs-walkthroughs-howto-and-examples.aspx